# Getting empty result set using multiple AND statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has a fk, pk, and dates.  There are many fk rows with dates for each foreign key.

I'm trying select distinct fk values with multiple dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.fk
FROM table
WHERE table.date = 'date1'
   AND table.date = 'date2'
   AND table.date = 'date3'
```

It works for one date, but when I add any additional ANDs, it returns no results.  I know there are fks with multiple dates that I'm asking for.

When I look at the query plan for single dates it looks good and I have all the right indexes, when I look at a query plan for multiple dates it just shows a "Constant Scan" that is 100% of the query cost and a SELECT which is 0%.

I've also tried selecting pk using the same predicates but I get the same empty result set.

Comment: In your query you're saying that the date is a 'date1' AND 'date2' AND 'date3' which is not possible, you need to use `OR`s or `IN`

Answer (score 2):

Of course the `date` can't be `date1` and `date2` at the same time. I assume you need this:

```
WHERE table.date = 'date1'
   OR table.date = 'date2'
   OR table.date = 'date3'
```

or

```
WHERE table.date IN ('date1', 'date2', 'date3')
```

Comment: I am not reading the question that way.  "distinct fk values with multiple dates"  I am pretty sure OP wants fk with all those dates not any of those dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for
This will be the fk that have all three dates (not any of the three)
This will include fk that have exactly all three dates and fk that have all three dates and additional dates.

```
select fk 
  from table 
 where date in ('date1','date2','date3') 
 group by fk  
having count(distinct(date)) = 3
```

If the the pk in table is fk, date then you can just use count(*)

You can also do it with join or intersect but this is simplest (I think)

A where only evaluates a single row at a time
Date = date1 and Date = date2 will always be false (if date1 <> date2)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass different dates, its impossible to match more than one time.

ex:

```
WHERE table.date = '20140410'
AND table.date = '20130410'
AND table.date = '20120410'
```

You cant reach this condition.

use table.date IN ('date1', 'date2', 'date3') instead